# connect asp.net application to telephone infrastructure

Tags: asp.net, tapi

I am having a ASP.net web application which is hosted in an internet server. Now i got a requirement to integrate this website with a computer telephony infrastructure. The details are as follows.

The user will be located in a building having TAPI standard, LAN – CTE infrastructure enabled telephone system and the logged-in user should be able to connect to the phone line (extension no:) within the same building through the browser. When a call comes to that phone line, a popup should appear in the users browser displaying the number of the caller. I am having the following doubts in implementation of this functionality

How should I connect (communicate) my application with this LAN – CTE infrastructure? The LAN – CTE infrastructre is simply an API having no web services exposed from their side for this purpose. So think I will have to write an extra wrapper class just above the LAN – CTE infrastructure to facilitate this. Please have your thoughts and suggestion on this.

Do I really need to connect to the telephone line across the internet as this logged user and the extension no: will be in the same local network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write a service and install that service on the machine where the TAPI TSP is installed. you could access your service via service-calls from your websites (e.g. via webservice).

for the service part: http://www.julmar.com/tapi/ here is a good starting point.

we have developed the scenario you are writing. we have a central installation of our CRM system, and in the branches of the customers is only the above mentioned service installed.